# Updating Mysql database data using Php and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to set up a button which when clicked adds a fixed number to the database value. The database is called `var_stat` and consists of `id` and `value`. The table has one row so far where `id = var` and `value = 35`. If clicked, the button should add 5 to the value making it 40.

I'm not sure what to do here, as all answers I found used a completely different approach and strings instead of integers. So far I have done this:

```php
if (isset($_POST['n'])){
$n = $_POST['n'] ;
$stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE var_stat SET value = value + $n WHERE id = ? ');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$id = "var";
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

```
<script src="js/jQuery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script>
   function add(n){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
            'n' : n
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
        alert("Record successfully updated");
        }
    });
 }
  </script>
```

```html
<form>
<input type="button" value="+5" class="btn btn-circle btn-grey col-sm-10" onclick="add(5);">
</form>
```

If I change `$n` in the `update.php` to an `integer` and run the `update.php` by itself it works, however I can't seem to get this to run through my html page, so I guess there's something wrong with my javascript code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the `n` as well, move the `id` before the binding statement

```
if (isset($_POST['n'])){
    $n = $_POST['n'] ;
    $id = "var";
    $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE var_stat SET value = value + ? WHERE id = ? ');
    $stmt->bind_param('is',$n, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: It seems like my comment didn't go through. It works like a charm, thank you very much for helping!